# Remove symbols from ansible stdout_lines in file with Ansible

Tags: ansible, regexp-replace

A have the line in file acounts.list

```
['# name prueba7@prueba7.com', 'zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE']
```

I would like to remove `['# name`, all `'` and `']` What would the result be `prueba7@prueba7.com, zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE`

I tried to create task to remove first `['# name`

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /home/acounts.list
    state: absent
    regexp: "^\[\'\#\sname\s"
```

... but i got error. Could you please help with solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use replace instead:

```
- name: replace
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /home/acounts.list
    regexp: "['\\[\\]]|# *name *"
    replace: ''
```

you could write too: `regexp: '[''\[\]]|# *name *'`

`['\\[\\]]`  means replace all `'` or `[` or `]`  (or == [])

so as [ and ] are special char, you ahve to protect by `\`  with `"`  you have to protect `\` too by another `\`  (not needed when surrounded by ')

`|`  means `or`   and the other expression is `# *name *`   `*`  means zero or more space

Comment: Thank you so much! It really works!

Could you please Explain how this code works?

Comment: i have added some explanations